# Switching a binding with a binding

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, data-binding

I have a BlogStore class which contains two observablecollections like so

```
public class BlogStore {
    public ObservableCollection<Blog> blogs ...

    public ObservableCollection<Blog> favourites ...
}

public BlogStore blogStore ...
```

no I want to reuse a control which does the following binding

```
ItemsSource="{Binding blogStore.blogs}
```

so that I can switch to `favourites`, the following does not work, but I would like something in a similar vein.

```
ItemsSource={Binding blogStore{Binding category, ElementName=blogControl}
```

and in the controls code behind i would have a dependency property.

maybe a converter could do the trick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you treat `BlogStore` as a ViewModel then it would expose a couple of other properties.

`Category` to which you bind what ever control you are using to choose the category to display.

Also a `CategoryBlogs` property which returns either the value of `blogs` or `favourites` depending on the value of `Category`.

You would be implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` so you would ensure that a `PropertyChanged` event is fired for "CategoryBlogs" when the `Category` property is changed.

You would be binding `ItemsSource` just to  `CategoryBlogs`.

Comment: how would I pass a parameter to the ViewModel? can I add a property to blogStore as a ViewModel.

Comment: I figured it out by adding a DependencyProperty called Category and a property called relevant which it's getter returned either blog or favourite depending on the dependency properties value.